# Best way to split large mysql tables into multiple tables and read from them in a php application?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am storing information, usually around 1000 times per day, so about 1000 rows are added to a table daily. Currently I am reaching the 100k mark and I was wondering what the best solution would be to possibly split this data up monthly or weekly but still be able to select the data when the stored data is viewed in the application.

are there any good ways of splitting this data up automatically and then creating a query that will read from all or a few of the tables which are created depending what time period is viewed?

Comment: Loop up *Partitioning* for instance.

Comment: Partitioning will allow this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: *Why* do you want to split this up in the first place? Is 100k some magic number in your religion you're not allowed to cross or something?

Comment: @deceze No, but I expect the amount of rows added daily to increase with time, eventually it will become an issue and I want to try to prevent it. Thanks for the other comments, I will check that out.

Comment: 1000 a day is nothing to worry about. I'm running code that adds 50k per day and has been running for a few years without a problem. Database is over 100GBs is size and runs just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have MySQL tables with over a billion rows in them, and the server hasn't broken a sweat yet.  If it were to do so, I would just fire up a second box and enable a sharded cluster.  That's my recommendation to you.

http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html

Comment: Interesting, I guess I should read up on things more before I make assumptions :)

Comment: @MarkusTenghamn The raw number of rows isn't a problem... what you're doing with them may be, but those problems are generally separate from the volume of a table.  Build your data structure to fit your data.  You should be using efficient column types anyway.  And plan ahead a bit... remember that schema changes with huge amounts of data are not fast, and could require that you have downtime.